# Admin Password,change farm password

Tags: password, farm-admin

How can I change the admin password for SharePoint farm and site, without affecting the whole site or having SharePoint go down?

Comment: Farm means farm administrator? What you mean site, are you talking about site collection admin?

Comment: yes I mean Farm Admin,and the SharePoint site

Answer (score 2):

For the farm account, do the following

- change the password farm admin account in active directory
- now go to central admin> security> configure managed account...on this page click edit on the farm account
- now select the option "use existing password" and enter the new password which you did on step 1
- wait for couple of min and then test
- in some cases you may have to reset IIS

This will cause brief outage for whole sharepoint farm.

For site collection

Sharepoint don't store the password of site collection level useri.e. Site collection admin etc.
You can change password it anytime and will not cause the issue.

- change the password At active directory
- Now login to site collection with new password

Answer (score 0):

Here are some Reference links,

[Step by Step: Changing the SharePoint 2013 Farm Account Password](http://www.trustsharepoint.com/2015/06/step-by-step-changing-sharepoint-2013.html)

[Changing SharePoint 2013 farm passwords](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mbakirov/2016/07/29/changing-sharepoint-farm-passwords/)

[SharePoint 2010 – Service Accounts Passwords Change Guide](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charliechirapuntu/2013/01/16/sharepoint-2010-service-accounts-passwords-change-guide/)